# Django |add: on PK URL tag

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to get the next PK value using |add:"1" in the HTML template. 
My question is how do I get it to work? Example if PK is 1 it should be 2 after clicking the link. See code.

template

```
 <h3>
    <a href="{% url 'step' task_pk=step.task.pk step_pk=step_id|add:"1" %}">Next Step</a>
</h3>
```

models

```
class Task(models.Model):
CATEGORIES = (
    ('tr', 'Traffic'),
    ('cr', 'Conversion Rate'),
    ('br', 'Bounce Rate'),
    ('ma', 'Marketing'),
    ('sc', 'Sales Channels'),
    ('cur', 'Customer Relations'),
)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
description = models.CharField(max_length=300)
category = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CATEGORIES)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class Step(models.Model):
task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
order = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
description = models.TextField()
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['order']
    unique_together = ("task", "order")

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

views

```
def task_step(request, task_pk, step_pk):
step = get_object_or_404(Step, task_id=task_pk, pk=step_pk)
return render(request, 'totd/task_step.html', {'step': step})
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
re_path(r'(?P<task_pk>\d+)/(?P<step_pk>\d+)/$', views.task_step, name='step'),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to hand in the next_step id as part of the context. That way you can check that the value exists in the DB first and you won't get an ReverseMatch error when the template is rendered.

```
def task_step(request, task_pk, step_pk):
    step = get_object_or_404(Step, task_id=task_pk, pk=step_pk)
    next_step_pk = step_pk + 1

    # Use a filter operation so if there is no item with this pk it won't fail but will return an empty queryset
    next_step = Step.objects.filter(pk=next_step_pk)
    # Check the next step pk has a DB entry and set it to None if it doesn't exist
    if next_step.count() == 0:
        next_step_pk = None
    return render(request, 'totd/task_step.html', {'step': step,
                                                   'next_step_pk': next_step_pk})
```

Then you will have access to this context in your template and you can render the link only if it exists.

```
{% if next_step_pk %}
     <h3>
        <a href="{% url 'step' task_pk=step.task.pk step_pk=next_step_pk %}">Next Step</a>
    </h3>
{% endif %}
```